# why bootstrap modal hide after form submited?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have below code, and i am using bootstap modal(a popout dialog), and when i click "Add" button , will submit the form, just like the jquery code showing. but I dont know why after the form submited , the modal will automatically hide, how to control this to make it still there after the form submitted?

```
    $("#personDialogAddPersonBtn").click(
            function(){
                $("#documentFile").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#announcementForm").attr("action","${contextPath}/announcement/addAnnoPubToPerson.action");
                $("#announcementForm").submit();
            }       
        );


<div id="addPersonDialog"class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Add Person" aria-hidden="true">

 ...

 <div class="modal-footer">
  <a class="bt bt-pane b1" id="personDialogAddPersonBtn">Add</a>
  <a class="bt" id="personDialogCloseBtn">Close</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form via a regular POST request or are using an AJAX POST request. It looks like you are doing a regular POST request, so that would reload the page it seems.

Comment: Quite likely your page is refreshing as you do not seem to be submitting via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use `event.preventDefault()` and you may want to submit the form via ajax:

```
$("#announcementForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#documentFile").attr("disabled", true);
    $.post( "${contextPath}/announcement/addAnnoPubToPerson.action", $(this).serialize() ).done(function(data) {
        //success
    })
    .fail(function() {
        //error
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .ajax() to send your POST asynchronously and avoid the refresh.

If your application plays well with JSON objects, you can serialize your form, create the json object and send it to your app.

```
$('#personDialogAddPersonBtn').click(function() {    

    data = $("#announcementForm").serializeObject();
    data = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: '${contextPath}/announcement/addAnnoPubToPerson.action'
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        cache:false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert('Form submitted')
        },
        error: function(response){
            alert('Error submitting form)
        }
    });

});

$.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
```